# React - Attaching click handler to dynamic children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I'm trying to display a playlist in my electron app which uses react+flux.
For some reason I can not attach a click handler to each playlist item.

Here's my code:

```
var Playlist = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        var list = this.props.list;
        var playlist = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
            playlist.push(
                <PlaylistItem song={list[i]} key={i} />
            );
        }

        return (
            <ul className='playlist'>
                {playlist}
            </ul>
        )
    }

});

var PlaylistItem = React.createClass({

    _play: function() {
        console.log(this.props.song);
    },

    render: function() {
        var song = this.props.song;

        return (
            <li>
                <div className='playBtn'>
                    <i className='fa fa-play' onClick={this._play}>
                    </i>
                </div>
                <div className='info'>
                    <div className='artist'>{song.artist}</div>
                    <div className='title'>{song.title}</div>
                </div>
                <div className='rmBtn'>
                    <i className='fa fa-minus-circle'>
                    </i>
                </div>
                <div className='time'>{song.time}</div>
            </li>
        );
    }

});
```

I don't understand why the click handler never fires. I'd expect that when clicking the i element i'd get the song object to the console.

Thanks.

Edit: I did some experimenting with this and everytime I get the data from a store (even fake data) the click handlers don't work. But if I move the fake data into the root component the click handlers work fine.

I have checked that the objects in the array are identical multiple times.

I don't understand why this behaviour is happening.

Anyone?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5758b33y/. You do have the font-awesome stuff already running right?

Comment: Yeah, everything looks right, I just don't get any click handler to work in PlaylistItem.

Comment: In the fiddle I have above when I click the play icon, I get a message in the console which is what it looks like you are trying to do. Do you not get that?

Comment: I can confirm what noveyak is telling, all works fine.

Comment: Yeah I tried hard coding the list data and it works. For some reason the data I pass on from the store breaks it. I will have to look into it later today. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the answer? I have the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the onClick method
`onClick={this._play.bind(this)}`

Comment: Bind only tells the function what "this" means and won't help me in this instance.

Comment: Actually that seems to be the issue though - the clickHandler loses its reference to PlaylistItem - hence doesn't probably know what `_play` is.

With the bind `this` refers again to PlaylistItem and the method can be called.

Answer (score -1):

I have experienced this problem myself and resolved it as follows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32623836/852872. Hope this helps for you too.

Answer from that page

> I haven't done any deeper investigation why this didn't work for me,
>   but the problem was that in my main file I imported React as
>   require('React'), but on other components as require('React/addons').
>   After importing React everywhere from react/addons everything works as
>   expected.

Comment: If this question is a duplicate of the one you've linked, please flag it as a duplicate. Otherwise, please provide a complete answer to this question instead of a link-only answer.