# React onClick event is not fired when element is created in for loop

Tags: coffeescript, reactjs

I was trying to solve this strange problem all day, but didn't managed to. This is one of the first days I am trying out React, so maybe I am missing something.

**ParentComponent.cjsx**

```
module.exports = React.createClass
    getInitialState: ->
        {
            items: []
        }

    componentDidMount: ->
        request.get(constants.API_ROOT + @props.source)
               .end((err, res) =>
                    @setState({items: res.body})
        )

    render: ->
        `
        // First try: DOES NOT WORK
        var items = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++) {
            var item = this.state.items[i];
            items.push(<ChildItem key={item.id} id={item.id} name={item.name} src={item.image_url_640x480} />)
        }
        console.log(['items1', items]);

        // Second try: DOES NOT WORK
        var origThis = this;
        var items2 = this.state.items.map(function (item) {
            return (<ChildItem key={item.id} id={item.id} name={item.name} src={item.image_url_640x480} />);
        }.bind(origThis), origThis);
        console.log(['items2', items2]);

        `

        // Creating elements by hand (WORKS, but not helpful at all)
        items3 = [
            <ChildItem key=23 id=31 name='ddd' src='adasdas' />,
            <ChildItem key=12 id=13 name='bg' src='/media/cache/de/ba/deba6d1545e209b0416b501c61fe031f.jpg' />
        ]
        console.log(items3)
        <div id="image-layer-selector" className="pure-g">{items1} {items2} {items3}</div>
```

**ChildItem.cjsx**

```
module.exports = React.createClass
    getInitialState: ->
        selected: false

    handleClick: ->
        console.log 'clicked'
        @setState selected: true


    render: ->
        elemClasses = classnames('pure-u-1-2', 'selector-element', {'selected': @state.selected})
        <div className={elemClasses} onClick={@handleClick}>
            {@props.name} - {@props.id}
            <img className="pure-img" src={constants.API_ROOT + @props.src}/>
        </div>
```

ChildItem onClick handler is fired only when elements are set by hand. What am I missing? I tried a lot of possible ways in .cjsx, plain .jsx, .map function, plain JS for loop etc. None of these seemed to work. Console doesn't contain any errors.

Using react 13.3.

**EDIT**. Seems like onClick handler doesn't work only when items are set in `componentDidMount` using `setState`. Identical problem without solution is here: [React - Attaching click handler to dynamic children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528079/react-attaching-click-handler-to-dynamic-children)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem. I haven't done any deeper investigation why this didn't work, but the problem was that in my main file I imported React as `require('React')`, but on other components as `require('React/addons')`. After importing React everywhere from `react/addons` everything works as expected.